# BizTalk Static send ports changing the address(URI) using WMI script or updating in bts_sendport_transport not working

Tags: c#, biztalk, biztalk-2010

I am trying to change the static send port URI from BizTalk admin console by opening the configuration, I am able to do change the URI.

But if I do the send port `URIchange` using WMI script in c# or directly update on `bts_sendport_transport`, it changes the URI in database and the change appears in the send port list also.

Bur when I open the MQ configuration, I can still find the old URI in MQ definition.

Can any one please help me to change the MQ definition in send ports without using admin console?

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach  to the problem is wrong they invernted dynamic ports for your problem. since your question not clear enough may be I don't understand your problem clearly.

Here is link for Dynamic Ports and Usage http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/502425/BizTalk-Static-and-Dynamic-FTP-Send-Port-Sample

you must focus on last part

```html
Msg_DynamicSend(FTP.CommandLogFileName) =  "D:\\BiztalkLogs\\FTPLog\\DynamicFTPLog.txt";
Msg_DynamicSend(FTP.UserName) =  "FTPUSER";
Msg_DynamicSend(FTP.Password) =  "Pass1234";
Msg_DynamicSend(FTP.SpoolingFolder) =  "/IN/";
Msg_DynamicSend(FTP.RepresentationType) =  "ASCII";
DynSendPort(Microsoft.XLANGs.BaseTypes.Address)= "ftp://inhydeshrilata"; 
DynSendPort(Microsoft.XLANGs.BaseTypes.TransportType) = "FTP"
```